# What is custom asynchronous validation function in strongloop?

Tags: node.js, strongloop

Can you please explain the meaning and use of validateAsync function of strongloop.[enter link description here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Validatable+class#validatable-validateasync)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's used to validate the name property on the User model in the example. It checks if the provided name is equal to "bad" and returns an error if it is. The example also shows you how to validate using the async and sync styles.